# AngularJS: Target a form with Controller As syntax in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-controller

Note: I did look around here on SO for solutions, yet no one had the additional issue of the function being in an object.

I have a form in my Angular JS app:

```
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="PMTController as pmt">
   <form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pmt.search.resetSearchForm()">Reset</button>
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Further, I have a controller with an object:

```
app.controller('PMTController', function($log) {
  var _this = this;

  _this.search = {
    resetSearchForm: function () {
     $log.debug('test');
     // how to target the form?
   }
 };
})
```

My ng-click works, as the log.debug works.  But no amount of tweaking to target the form so that I can reset the entire thing (empty all the fields) works.

I can do `$window.myForm.reset();` but how could I do this from angular?

Note please my main issue/question is how to **correctly target the form** from inside that `resetSearchForm` function in the `search` object.

Note I tried changing the form name to `pmt.myForm` or `pmt.search.myForm` to no avail.

I tried `$setPristine` and `$setUntouched()` but they don't seem to clear the fields.

I know I can assign a model and assign it to all the form controls, but this is for a prototype so I'd rather do a simple reset.

I made a pen: https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/YWOPPq?editors=1011#0

Comment: your input isn't bound to angular in any way (has no `ng-model`) and has no `id`, so it wouldn't be possible for angular to maintain the data for it.

Comment: I will try it, but note I cannot seem to correctly target the form itself from inside that function.  I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: because the object created to represent the form is a special object in angular, that only contains inputs which it has bindings for.  there is no way for angular to change the values of form fields it doesn't have a binding over.

Comment: if you evaluate the `pmt.myForm` object, `$dirty` is still false, even after making changes to the input, because that input isn't bound.

Comment: as to your update, if your form is named `pmt.myForm`, then it will be accessible in the controller as `_this.myForm`;  however, this isn't the object that is on `$window`, so `reset()` isn't valid for it, and the other angular methods only affect angular bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your codepen that will hopefully resolve the issue:

https://codepen.io/watsoncn/pen/YWOXqZ?editors=1011

Explanation:

Angular's documentation provides an example of a "Form Reset" button, but you can apply the same logic towards resetting after submission:

`Documentation:`https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

with a plunker:

`Live Example:`https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

The example shows the use of Angular's [copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) method that creates a deep copy of whatever you pass it as a parameter and assigns it to the ng-model that is put on a particular input field. In this case they simply pass it an empty master object.

You need to make sure to add an ng-model attribute to your inputs, then create a reset function that can run *after* submission. Another common option would be to simply set each input's ng-model to empty strings in the submission function, such as `$scope.inputModel = ""`

Is this what you were hoping for? I might have misunderstood the question. I will happily take another crack at it if there is still confusion.

Comment: He's using `controller-as-syntax`.. not `$scope`.

Comment: Hmmm... unless controllerAs is set in a config, I believe $scope will be needed view2controller data flow, correct? I'll add an updated CodePen

Comment: this just serves to validate my comments that a binding is necessary for angular to affect the form.  however, you definitely **do not** need `$scope` here....

Answer (score 0):

To get the form in your controller you just need to name your form this way:

```
<form name="pmt.myForm">
```

Here's a complete **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module('plunker', [])
    .controller('PMTController', PMTController);

  PMTController.$inject = ['$log'];

  function PMTController($log) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.model = {};
    
    _this.search = {
      resetSearchForm: function() {
        console.log(_this.myForm); // -> Form reference
        _this.model = {};
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="PMTController as pmt">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form name="pmt.myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="pmt.model.example" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="pmt.model.example2" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="pmt.model.example3" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="pmt.search.resetSearchForm()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <hr> All fields:
    <pre ng-bind="pmt.model | json"></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```